# IOS push notification issue on appcelerator

Tags: apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i have a big problem on my IOS app. I follow the guide provide by appcelerator documentation to setup my iOS push notification. All seemed work fine, on my appcelerator dashboard i see under the device section my device registered with its token, and when i send a push notification on the detail's push (in push notification log) i read my id device number with a perfect Success(1).

But on my device i didn't receive any notification. I tried with my app opened and with my app closed, but nothing has showed. I don't know why this happen. On my android all work fine. Here my code:

```
//PUSH NOTIFICATION
var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");
//controllo se ho un token
var deviceToken = Ti.App.Properties.getString("deviceToken");

if ( deviceToken == "" || deviceToken == null) {
    requireToken();
} else {

    if ( Ti.App.Properties.getString("subscribed") !== "true" ) {
        subscribeToChannel(deviceToken);
    }

}

//chiedo un token
function requireToken() {

    // Check if the device is running iOS 8 or later
    if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {
     Ti.API.warn( "entrato nella versione" )
        // Wait for user settings to be registered before registering for push notifications
        Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('usernotificationsettings', function registerForPush() {

            // Remove event listener once registered for push notifications
            Ti.App.iOS.removeEventListener('usernotificationsettings', registerForPush); 

            Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
                success: deviceTokenSuccess,
                error: deviceTokenError,
                callback: receivePush
            });
        });

        // Register notification types to use
        Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
            types: [
                Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
                Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
                Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE
            ]
        });

    }

    // For iOS 7 and earlier
    else {

        Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            // Specifies which notifications to receive
            types: [
                Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,
                Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
                Ti.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND
            ],
            success: deviceTokenSuccess,
            error: deviceTokenError,
            callback: receivePush
        });

    }

    function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        Ti.API.warn( "token ricevuto" )
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("deviceToken", e.deviceToken);
        subscribeToChannel(e.deviceToken);
    }
    function deviceTokenError(e) {
       //error action
    }

}

//controllo se sono iscritto alle notifiche push
if ( Ti.App.Properties.getString("subscribed") !== "true" ) {
    subscribeToChannel(deviceToken);
}


function subscribeToChannel (_deviceToken) {
        Ti.API.warn( "subscribe fatta" )
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken({
        device_token: _deviceToken,
        channel: "ios_alerts",
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
                Ti.App.Properties.setString("subscribed", "true");
        }
    });

};

function receivePush(e) {
    Ti.API.warn("alert ricevuto" + JSON.stringify(e) )
    alert(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is probably something related to your certificates on Apple panel.
Check if you enabled APS with your appid and if not, activate it, then generate another provisioning profiles and re-build the app.
You will also have to put a .p12 file in the Appcelerator platform website.

Comment: i tried change some certificate but i didn't resolve anything. How is it possible that i see success on my appcelerator dashboard and the notification doesn't arrive on my device without the certificate?

Comment: ok i deleted ALL certificate and redo all and now finally working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is your issue(s):

1. Device Token Cannot be fetched if on Device in Debug mode, must be in Run Mode!
2. Remember that under ad-hock releases push notifications MUST use the sandbox 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'

Chris

Ref: https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/148135/no-reply-from-tinetworkregisterforpushnotifications